# list assignment index out of range (creating a minesweeper board)

Tags: python, python-3.x

im receiving `"list assignment index out of range"`

```
def createBoard(rows, cols, mines):
    board = []
    for n_row in range(rows):
        board.append([])
    for n_col in range(cols):
        board.append([])

 # Place a random letter at each location in the board
 for n_row in range(rows):
     for n_col in range(cols):
         board[n_row][n_col] = ("C")
```

Comment: I suggest you print `board` before the second section. It's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do it, board is one list with (rows + cols) empty lists inside of it, not a list with rows columns each with rows spaces between them. what you wanna do is create a list with rows lists inside of them, and then append 'C' cols times, like so:

```
def createBoard(rows, cols, mines):
    board = []
    for n_row in range(rows):
        board.append([])

    for n_row in range(rows):
        for n_col in range(cols):
            board[n_row].append("C")
    return board #add this line if you wish the function to actually return the board
```

running

```
global_board = createBoard(3,3,4)
print(global_board)
```

gives me:

```
[['C', 'C', 'C'], ['C', 'C', 'C'], ['C', 'C', 'C']]
```

Comment: that makes sense, but now im getting feedback that "The value returned was a <class 'NoneType'>, not a list."

Comment: @kristofsole - Then maybe you should `return` something. Please review your textbook or other course materials.

Comment: i have a global board at the end of the function to use in later functions

Comment: @kristofsole - Then whatever automated checker gave you that "The value returned..." error message doesn't want you to do that.

Comment: @kristofsole i added the return in the end. I've tested it and it works on my computer. just get your global board and do `global_board = createBoard(3,3,5)` or whatever values you wanna use

Comment: my code has changed a lot in the past while, but it is working and now all that is left is to randomly change "mines" amount of values into "C*". hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your nested `for` loops where you are attempting to initialize each location in the board to `("C")` you are indexing locations up to a value equal to `cols`. However, in your `createBoard` you are appending empty lists to your `board` object. Therefore the location referenced by `board[n_row][n_col]` does not actually exist and thus the error.

You should print `board` after creating it to make sure it is the dimensions that you expect.

---

If you would like to initialize the board with the letter C in each location you can do as follows. You can combine the initialize and create phases together.

```
def createBoard(rows, cols, mines):
    board = []
    for n_row in range(rows):
        row = []
        row.extend(['C'] * cols)
        board.append(row)
    return board
```

`for n_row in range(rows)` gives you `rows` number of rows. `['C'] * cols` will create a list with `cols` number of 'C' in it that you can place in each row.

Comment: its giving me what i need, but in later parts of the code im going to have to call upon individual n_row, and n_col values

Comment: You can access or update any item in the board by `board[n_row][n_col]`.